# ¿Cómo contar el número de palabras que empiecen en mayúscula o minúscula?

Tags: c

Quisiera saber como hacer una función para que me cuente las palabras que empiezan con mayúscula o las que empiezan con minúscula.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

void contar (FILE *fp, int op_M, int op_m){
    int c, j;
    int contador = 0;
    int estado = OUT;

    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        if(op_M){
            if( c== ' ' || c == '\n' || c== '\t')
            estado = OUT;
            else if(estado == OUT){
                estado = IN;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tengo el `IN` y el `OUT` como un estado para saber si está dentro o fuera de la palabra, el problema que tengo es para saber como referenciar solo al primer carácter de la palabra, comprobar con `isupper()` si es mayúscula o minúscula y con ello incrementar el contador, creo que como se debe elegir una opción me valdría solo con un contador.

¿Podríais ayudarme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se resuelve asi, usando la función de clasificación `isupper`, que retorna Verdadero si el caracter es mayúsculas:

```
else { 
    if(estado == OUT){
         estado = IN;
         if (isupper(c)) {
             contador++;
             }
      }
```

La condición sólo se comprueba cuando el `estado` pase de OUT a IN, señalando el comienzo de una nueva palabra. En esta condición, `c` es la primera letra.

También puede reemplazar

```
if( c== ' ' || c == '\n' || c== '\t')
```

con

```
if (isspace(c))
```

`isspace` es otra función de clasificación que retorna Verdadero cuando `c` es un espacio en blanco o similar: \n, \t, \f, \r ...

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, voy a compilarlo y ver si funciona bien :)

Comment: Y una pregunta si quiero que cambie el primer caracter y deje el resto como esta, como se podría hacer? También podría usar esta función?

Comment: @RM. Has el intento, y si tienes problemas considera formular otra pregunta.